# Customize the org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

I have used below library for range seek-bar. But I want to change the thumb color and selected seek-bar color. How can I do it.help me I am new.

**XML code**

```
    <org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
             app:showLabels="false"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar2"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textAge"
             android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
             app:valuesAboveThumbs="false" />
```

---

**Java Code**

```
    ageSeekbar2 = (RangeSeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekbar2);
     ageSeekbar2.setRangeValues(18, 100);
            ageSeekbar2.setSelectedMaxValue(30);
            ageSeekbar2.getSelectedMaxValue();

            textAge.setText( ageSeekbar2.getSelectedMinValue() + "-" + ageSeekbar2.getSelectedMaxValue());


            ageSeekbar2.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
                  //  //Now you have the minValue and maxValue of your RangeSeekbar
                   // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), minValue + "-" + maxValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textAge.setText( minValue + "-" + maxValue);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can increase thickness of bar by adding this to your code:

```
    app:internalPadding="10dip"
```

Answer (score -1):

I went through the documentation of florescu's `RangeSeekBar`. Adding a few lines to your xml fill help get the desired effect.

```
<org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
             xmlns:rsb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             app:showLabels="false"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar2"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textAge"
             android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
             app:valuesAboveThumbs="false"
             rsb:textAboveThumbsColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
             rsb:thumbDisabled="@drawable/custom_slider_thumb"
             rsb:thumbNormal="@drawable/custom_slider_thumb"
             rsb:thumbPressed="@drawable/custom_slider_thumb"
             rsb:thumbShadow="true"
             rsb:thumbShadowBlur="3dp"
             rsb:thumbShadowColor="@color/primary_material_light"
             rsb:thumbShadowXOffset="1dp"
             rsb:thumbShadowYOffset="2dp"/>
```

Add a `drawable/custom_slider_thumb` with desired color.

Comment: Thanks. But how to change the thickness of line?Please tell me.

Comment: @Abhishek Did you find solution on how to change the thickness of line?

Comment: @elbertrivas using  rsb:barHeight="3dp" you can change thickness of bar

Comment: All.. does anybody know how to remove the "Max" "Min" labels on both sides of the seekbar?

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki set `rsb:showLabels="false"` to remove "Min" and "Max" labels